# i am trying to use the friend function but I am unable to access the private data members of my 2nd class

Tags: c++

I am trying to access the private members of the class through the friend function here below my code is code is in complete

```
#include<iostream>
#include<string>
#include<fstream>
using namespace std;
class time;
class date{
void friend  mixdatetime(date &c, time &d);
int day;
int month;
int year;
public:
date(int day, int month, int year){
    this->day = day;
    this->month = month;
    this->year = year;
}};
class time{
int hours;
int minutes;
int seconds;    
public:
time(int hours, int minutes, int seconds){
    this->hours = hours;
    this->minutes = minutes;
    this->seconds = seconds;}
void print(){};} ;
void mixdatetime(date &c, time &d){
c.day; // accessable
// why  //d.minutes // inacccess able };};
```

In this code when i try to access d.minutes or d.hours  // i can not because it is inaccessible why ? I am unable to access the private members kindly tell me appropriate solution

Comment: So this is nothing to do with C# right? Why did you tag that?

Comment: Please post an [MCVE], the error, and format your code properly. And don't spam tags.

Comment: why negative rating :3 I am just a beginner bros :/ Sorry for wrong  tag

Comment: any solution ???

Comment: This question is a complete mess, is probably why. Being "a beginner" is not an excuse; there are millions of other questions you could look at to see how it's done. It's also extremely basic - keep reading your C++ book to find out how to create and use classes.

Answer (score 1):

> why d.minutes inaccessible

because `minutes` is private to the class `time` and you did not declare `mixdatetime` as friend of the class `time`. Add the friendship declaration to the class `time` as well:

```
friend void mixdatetime(date &c, time &d);
```